# Reason for one of the scripts not getting executed in crontab, after a crash event in a NUC system

Tags: python-3.x, cron, crash

"launcher.sh" is invoked upon every reboot of the system (done through crontab)
In the launcher.sh, a main python script, a memory monitoring python script are invoked.

It works perfectly fine. Even upon reboot also, both the python scripts are getting executed successfully.

One day, by mistake, the NUC system (in which the scripts are running) power button was pressed accidentally(March 16, 12:10 pm). After that, the system gets rebooted; Only the memory monitoring python script was getting executed; Not the main python script.

(i) Can someone help us to understand the reason for this observation?

FYI: Later on, the system is restarted intensionally; Since then, it works fine. (Both the scripts are getting executed)

Pulled out the "last" and "last reboot" results from that system. Please find below:
'''

```
last reboot
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-1094-oem  Sun Mar 21 06:01   still running
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-1094-oem  Thu Mar 18 14:05 - 06:01 (2+15:56)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-1094-oem  Mon Mar 15 11:42 - 06:01 (5+18:18)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-1094-oem  Sun Mar 14 06:01 - 06:01 (6+23:59)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-1094-oem  Thu Mar 11 16:55 - 06:01 (2+13:06)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-1094-oem  Mon Mar  8 10:39 - 16:54 (3+06:15)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-1094-oem  Sun Mar  7 06:01 - 10:37 (1+04:35)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-1094-oem  Sat Mar  6 10:27 - 06:01  (19:33)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-1094-oem  Mon Mar  1 14:40 - 10:25 (4+19:45)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-1094-oem  Mon Mar  1 11:14 - 14:39  (03:25)

last 
linuxdev :0           :0               Sun Mar 21 06:02   still logged in
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-1094-oem  Sun Mar 21 06:01   still running
linuxdev :0           :0               Thu Mar 18 14:05 - 06:01 (2+15:55)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-1094-oem  Thu Mar 18 14:05 - 06:01 (2+15:56)
linuxdev :0           :0               Tue Mar 16 12:11 - crash (2+01:53)
linuxdev :0           :0               Mon Mar 15 11:42 - 12:10 (1+00:27)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-1094-oem  Mon Mar 15 11:42 - 06:01 (5+18:18)
linuxdev :0           :0               Sun Mar 14 06:02 - crash (1+05:39)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-1094-oem  Sun Mar 14 06:01 - 06:01 (6+23:59)
linuxdev :0           :0               Thu Mar 11 16:55 - down  (2+13:05)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-1094-oem  Thu Mar 11 16:55 - 06:01 (2+13:06)
linuxdev :0           :0               Mon Mar  8 10:40 - down  (3+06:14)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-1094-oem  Mon Mar  8 10:39 - 16:54 (3+06:15)
linuxdev :0           :0               Sun Mar  7 06:02 - down  (1+04:34)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-1094-oem  Sun Mar  7 06:01 - 10:37 (1+04:35)
linuxdev :0           :0               Sat Mar  6 10:28 - down   (19:32)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-1094-oem  Sat Mar  6 10:27 - 06:01  (19:33)
linuxdev :0           :0               Mon Mar  1 14:40 - down  (4+19:45)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-1094-oem  Mon Mar  1 14:40 - 10:25 (4+19:45)
linuxdev :0           :0               Mon Mar  1 11:14 - down   (03:24)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-1094-oem  Mon Mar  1 11:14 - 14:39  (03:25)
```

'''

A follow up question, (ii) when will we observe "crash" in "last" command?